# GCD concurrent queue not starting tasks in FIFO order

Tags: ios, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I have a class which contains two methods as per the example in Mastering Swift by Jon Hoffman. The class is as below:

```
class DoCalculation {
        func doCalc() {
           var x = 100
           var y = x * x
           _ = y/x
        }

        func performCalculation(_ iterations: Int, tag: String) {
           let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
           for _ in 0..<iterations {
              self.doCalc()
           }
           let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
           print("time for \(tag):  \(end - start)")
        }
}
```

Now in the viewDidLoad() of the ViewController from the single view template, I create an instance of the above class and then create a concurrent queue. I then add the blocks executing the performCalculation(: tag:) method to the queue.

```
cqueue.async {
            print("Starting async1")
            calculation.performCalculation(10000000, tag: "async1")
}

cqueue.async {
            print("Starting async2")
            calculation.performCalculation(1000, tag: "async2")
}

cqueue.async {
            print("Starting async3")
            calculation.performCalculation(100000, tag: "async3")
}
```

Every time I run the application on simulator, I get random out put for the start  statements. Example outputs that I get are below:

```
Example 1:
Starting async1
Starting async3
Starting async2
time for async2:  4.1961669921875e-05
time for async3:  0.00238299369812012
time for async1:  0.117094993591309

Example 2:
Starting async3
Starting async2
Starting async1
time for async2:  2.80141830444336e-05
time for async3:  0.00216799974441528
time for async1:  0.114436984062195

Example 3:
Starting async1
Starting async3
Starting async2
time for async2:  1.60336494445801e-05
time for async3:  0.00220298767089844
time for async1:  0.129496037960052
```

I don't understand why the blocks don't start in FIFO order. Can somebody please explain what am I missing here?
I know they will be executed concurrently, but its stated that concurrent queue will respect FIFO for starting the execution of tasks, but won't guarantee which one completes first. So at least the starting task statements should have started with

```
Starting async1
Starting async3
Starting async2
```

and this completion statements random:

```
time for async2:  4.1961669921875e-05
time for async3:  0.00238299369812012
time for async1:  0.117094993591309
```

and the completion statements random.

Comment: @Rob The race condition and Duncan's answer below do provide me with an explanation. Would you suggest some way to get the info when a Task is dequeued from the queue  so that I can log it to get the FIFO order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concurrent queue runs the jobs you submit to it *concurrently*That's what it's for.

If you want a queue the runs jobs in FIFO order, you want a serial queue.

I see what you're saying about the docs claiming that the jobs will be submitted in FIFO order, but your test doesn't really establish the order in which they're run. If the concurrent queue has 2 threads available but only one processor to run those threads on, it might swap out one of the threads before it gets a chance to print, run the other job for a while, and then go back to running the first job. There's no guarantee that a job runs to the end before getting swapped out.

I don't think a print statement gives you reliable information about the order in which the jobs are started.

Comment: You have cleared some of the ambiguity in my thinking. This really helps me get a better view  "If the concurrent queue has 2 threads available but only one processor to run those threads on, it might swap out one of the threads before it gets a chance to print"

Comment: Can you please suggest a way that to know which one was started instead of the print statements then?. Would breakpoints with Automatically continue after evaluating actions help. Will give them a try

Comment: Purely for testing purposes you could create a POSIX lock, lock it in each job before executing the print statement, do your print, and then unlock the lock. That would cause each thread to finish it's print before allowing the next thread to do it's print.

Comment: Note that doing that would only be as a way of testing the order of execution. Using locks would defeat the purpose of using a concurrent queue.

Answer (score 1):

"I don't understand why the blocks don't start in FIFO order" How do you know they don't? They do *start* in FIFO order!

The problem is that you have no way to *test* that. The notion of testing it is, in fact, incoherent. The soonest you can test anything is the first line of each block — and by *that* time, it is perfectly legal for *another* line of code from *another* block to execute, because these blocks are *asynchronous*. That is what asynchronous *means*.

So, they *start* in FIFO order, but there is no guarantee about the order in which, given multiple asynchronous blocks, their *first lines* will be executed.

Comment: I Earlier assumed that a block execution is started as soon as its first statement is executed. But now due to all the answers, it is bit more clearer that it might be set as started during the context switch. Correct me if my previous sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

cqueue is a *concurrent queue* which is dispatching your block of work to three different threads(it actually depends on the threads availability) at almost the same time but you can not control the time at which each thread completes the work.

If you want to perform a task serially in a background queue, you are much better using serial queue.

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")
```

Serial Queue will start the next task in queue only when your previous task is completed.

Comment: You pressed send before me. :)

Comment: @Pueet Sharma I know they will be executed concurrently, but its stated that concurrent queue will respect FIFO for starting the execution of tasks, but won't guarantee which one completes first. So at least the starting task statements should have started with 1, 2 , 3 and the completion random.

Comment: Note that the above works because the DispatchQueue init method creates a serial queue by default.

Comment: @RohanBhale: When you give a block of work to a queue, it gets completed in the same thread. It is not like it will print the first statement and then completes the other task in another thread. FIFO here means the dispatch of work to a thread will happen in that order, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @DuncanC Agreed but I am creating concurrent queue. Please check my updated question

Comment: @PuneetSharma how do I get to know that this block has been dispatched for work, so that I can observe it.

Comment: @RohanBhale: If you mean you want to debug, you can create a breakpoint inside the block.

Comment: @PuneetSharma I mean to say whats a better way if not print statements to know which one started first

Answer (score 0):

With a concurrent queue, you are effectively specifing that they can run at the same time. So while they’re added in FIFO manner, you have a race condition between these various worker threads, and thus you have no assurance which will hit its respective `print` statement first.

So, this raises the question: Why do you care which order they hit their respective print statements? If order is really important, you shouldn't be using concurrent queue. Or, the other way of saying that, if you want to use a concurrent queue, write code that isn't dependent upon the order with which they run.

You asked:

> Would you suggest some way to get the info when a Task is dequeued from the queue so that I can log it to get the FIFO order.

If you're asking how to enjoy FIFO starting of the tasks on concurrent queue in real-world app, the answer is "you don't", because of the aforementioned race condition. When using concurrent queues, never write code that is strictly dependent upon the FIFO behavior.

If you're asking how to verify this empirically for purely theoretical purposes, just do something that ties up the CPUs and frees them up one by one:

```
// utility function to spin for certain amount of time

func spin(for seconds: TimeInterval, message: String) {
    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    while CACurrentMediaTime() - start < seconds { }
    os_log("%@", message)
}

// my concurrent queue

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: label, attributes: .concurrent)

// just something to occupy up the CPUs, with varying 
// lengths of time; don’t worry about these re FIFO behavior

for i in 0 ..< 20 {
    queue.async {
        spin(for: 2 + Double(i) / 2, message: "\(i)")
    }
}

// Now, add three tasks on concurrent queue, demonstrating FIFO

queue.async {
    os_log("   1 start")
    spin(for: 2, message: "   1 stop")
}
queue.async {
    os_log("   2 start")
    spin(for: 2, message: "   2 stop")
}
queue.async {
    os_log("   3 start")
    spin(for: 2, message: "   3 stop")
}
```

You'll be able to see those last three tasks are run in FIFO order.

The other approach, if you want to confirm precisely what GCD is doing, is to refer to the [libdispatch source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch). It's admittedly pretty dense code, so it's not exactly obvious, but it's something you can dig into if you're feeling ambitious.